# How to pass "with clause" to a function in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

I have a templated class that contains a queue and has implemented similar queue functions like "push_back, pop_front, delete, etc." Basically I want this class to behave like a queue, but also do some additional bookkeeping (coverage and some checking) when adding or removing elements from the queue. When I'm using objects of this class, I need to perform a "find_index" on the queue, so I'm trying to implement a "find_index" function in my class that does the same, but I'm not able to figure out the syntax to pass a "with clause" to the function. I'm not sure if this is even possible in SystemVerilog. If not, is there a different solution I could use to achieve this behavior?

```
class my_queue #(type T);
    typedef T queue_t[$];
    typedef int int_q[$];
    protected queue_t m_queue;

    void push_back(T item);
        m_queue.push_back(item);
        //Other stuff
    endfunction

    function T pop_front();
       //Other stuff
       return m_queue.pop_front();
    endfunction

    //TODO: Get this working
    //function int_q find_index(/*with_clause_t with_clause*/);
    //    return m_queue.find_index(x) with (with_clause);
    //endfunction
endclass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement what is called a *policy* class or [decorator design pattern](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/521153a8e4b01a5565d75104/t/571d3b08746fb91673c11962/1461533459432/08_2.pdf). Basically it is a class whose only purpose is to act as virtual method that you pass as an argument to a function.

You know that function will be passed an `item` of the array and return true or false. That becomes the prototype

```
interface class find_index_policy#(typeT);
  pure virtual function bit f(T item);
endclass
...
function int_q find_index(find_index_policy fip);
       return m_queue.find_index(x) with (fip.f(item));
endfunction
```

Then you implement that class, construct an object of it and pass it to the find_index method of your class

```
class lt_policy#(type T = int) implements find_index_policy#(T);
  int limit;
  function new(int l); limit = l; endfunction 
  function bit f(T item);
    return item < limit; // equation you want your queue class to use
  endfunction
endclass

lt_policy lt= new(5);

q = my_q.find_index(lt);
```